# How do i convert a while loop to a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

```
while (counter < total)
{
inFile >> grade;
sum += grade;
counter++;
}
```

Above is the while loop I had for my original program and below is my attempt at converting that to a for loop.

```
for (counter = 0; counter < total; counter++)
{
    inFile >> grade;        
    cout << "The value read is " << grade << endl;
    total = total + grade;  
}
```

This is a simple program to get grade averages. Here is the entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int average (int a, int b);
int main()
{
// Declare variable inFile
    ifstream inFile;
// Declare variables
    int grade, counter, total;
// Declare and initialize sum
    int sum = 0;
// Open file 
    inFile.open("input9.txt");
// Check if the file was opened
    if (!inFile)
    {
    cout << "Input file not found" << endl;
    return 1;
    }
// Prompt the user to enter the number of grades to process.
    cout << "Please enter the number of grades to process: " << endl << endl;
    cin >> total;
// Check if the value entered is outside the range (1…100).
    if (total < 1 || total > 100)
    {
        cout << "This number is out of range!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
// Set counter to 0.
    counter = 0;
// While (counter is less than total)
    // Get the value from the file and store it in grade.
    // Accumulate its value in sum.
    // Increment the counter.
    while (counter < total)
    {
    inFile >> grade;
    sum += grade;
    counter++;
    }
// Print message followed by the value returned by the function average (sum,total).
    cout << "The average is: " << average(sum,total) << endl << endl;

    inFile.close();

    return 0;

}
int average(int a, int b)
{   

return static_cast <int> (a) /(static_cast <int> (b));
}
```

I tried to convert while loop to a for loop but when I debug I get an infinite loop. There are no errors when I build my solution. I'm not sure what other details to add.

Comment: It was just a matter of a second look before you posted it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are increasing the value of `total` in the `for` loop. Hence, `counter` never reached `total` if you keep entering positive values.

Perhaps you meant to use `sum` instead of `total` in the loop.

```
for (counter = 0; counter < total; counter++)
{
    inFile >> grade;        
    cout << "The value read is " << grade << endl;
    sum = sum + grade;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong variables names, value of `total` is increasing in the for loop so it becomes an infinite loop, use a different variable names for storing sum and for `for-loop` termination condition.